# Mapping Requestbody to JSONObject in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a class as below.

```
class ExampleBean{
   public String Name;
   public JSONObject data;
}
```

And i have @GET handler which is as follows:

```
@GET
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getData(ExampleBean dataBean)
{
    // some usage code here
}
```

I want following json to be mapped to the ExmampleBean:

```
{
  "Name":"Example",
  "data":{
       "hello":"world",
       "some":"value"
   }
 }
```

Everything works perfectly if `data` was a type which had two public fields named `hello` and `some`. But since `data` is a JSONObject which doesn't actually have those fields or relevant setters it ends up throwing  `Unrecognized field "hello" (Class JSONObject), not marked as ignorable at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@17b9a4bf; line: 31, column: 18]`

Comment: `Map<String,Object>`?

Comment: I have successfully mapped `JsonNode` on toplevel. Does it work when you change your jsonobject to jsonnode?

Answer (score 1):

Try with JsonNode. It is working.

Class: **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode**

Answer (score 0):

ignore the data property when  forming the object from incoming request.

```
class ExampleBean{
   public String Name;
   @JsonIgnore
   public JSONObject data;
}
```

and change the rest service to accept data as a parameter from the incoming request.

```
@GET
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getData(@RequestBody ExampleBean dataBean,RequestParam("data") String data)
{

 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(data);
    // some usage code here
}
```

or you can change the datatype of `JsonObject data` to `String` and form an `object` from the incoming request.

```
 class ExampleBean{
 public String Name;
 public String data;
 }
```

and later create an Json object from the data string

```
      @GET
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getData(@RequestBody ExampleBean dataBean)
{

 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(dataBean.data);
    // converting the string data to jsonobject
}
```

Comment: I have tried `@JsonIgnore`. Didn't work. Is it different from `@jsonignore` ?

Comment: sorry, that was a typing mistake, have u tried the second method ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have the requirement to pass your @RequestBody as JSONObject or/and return the output as JSONObject. The most convenient approach I follow is:

1. Accept the @RequestBody as String (You can also accept as your Object Data Type) and internally in your Post Mapping method, convert to JSONObject. For ex:

```
@GET
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public String getData(@RequestBody String jsonObjectData)
{
    JSONObject parsedJsonData = new JSONObject(jsonObjectData);
    // other implementation
}
```

2. Before you return the JSONObject from your method, convert it to the String or your Object Data type

```
return JsonObjectToReturn.toString(); // or you can parse it to your return Object data type.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Map` or `JsonNode` rather than `JSONObject`. Because those are woking well with `Jackson`. Like follows,

```
class ExampleBean {
   public String Name;
   public Map<String, String> data;
}
```

or

```
class ExampleBean {
   public String Name;
   public JsonNode data;
}
```